# Send object with on-click functions of Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to send object as params of on-click functions, I already saw some posts using data-xxx to send values and retrieving them with the target.attributes field but that works only for strings and not objects.

Here is a jsbin showing the problem: http://jsbin.com/tujekilafowa/1/edit?html,console,output

There is a solution, even though its terrible, by using JSON.stringify to send the data and retrieving them with JSON.parse: http://jsbin.com/lavocacadoti/1/edit?html,console,output

Is there a better way?

In a perfect world, I would like it to work as Angular by passing parameters to a function directly inside the HTML call...

**EDIT**

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/723) on polymer project about this problem.

Comment: I encountered this situation before. And, the only sane way that I could find was storing the objects in a collection or an array passing the 'id' of that particular object to the `onClickFunction` and retrieving it back from the array.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your method please?

Comment: [Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sbxbt25c/) in which the onclick functions passes the index of the location at which the element is present. You can easily tweak the code to instead send 'id' or some other unique attribute of the object and then in the handler function identify the object by looping over your array of items.

Comment: I get the idea, it is "sane" but far from ideal.
I guess Polymer is still too young to cover every use case.

Comment: I cant see your exact use case but what about using the sender.templateInstance.model data? lke this http://jsbin.com/codefapebe/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking Peters answer above, this works for me (if it is enough to access the model)...

Polymer Element Template:

```
<template>
    <template repeat="{{ address in addresses }}">
        <paper-button label="-" on-click="{{ callback }}">less</paper-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

The Polymer Callback looks like this:

```
Polymer({
    callback: function (event, detail, sender) {
        console.log(sender.templateInstance.model.address);
    }
});
```

Comment: As of Polymer 1.0 it becomes `event.model.address`

Comment: I've found that polymer ^1.5 doesn't populate the `event.model.xxx` variable even though the documentation clearly states it should. I found the iterating variable tucked in private api `event.model._config.xxx`

Comment: @victor it works fine for me in polymer^2.0 as the documentation states here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events